# Why our mails go to spam box in Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, spam-blocker

Please note that we are sending mails from the domain name `trendsinvogue.in` to Gmail. All mails going to spam folder only. Also the mail server ip is not listed in the spam database.

http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a198.15.80.99&run=toolpage

Please check and update us.

Comment: Do you have SPF, DKIM setup? Are you sending through MTA or via scripts?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure your emails go to the inbox folder of your users, you need to respect some guidelines from Google. Here are some points:

- Use the same address in the 'From:' header on every bulk mail you send
- A user must be able to unsubscribe from your mailing list
- All messages must be formatted according to RFC 5322 and, if using HTML, HTML standards
- Sign messages with DKIM
- Publish an SPF record
- Publish a DMARC policy
- ...

All the list is availlable on Google support site [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en#authentication).